# WCF functions not viewing in the client

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have created functions in `WCF` and tested them in `WCFTestClient.exe`. But when testing it on an actual client (mobile). It don't show the functions but the following only.

Example function name is `Plus();` it will show `PlusAsync();` with void as a return value. Also an event handler (I remember it was `PlusEventHandler` something).

Please advise me.

Comment: Paste your Service/Client code

Comment: is that work for you ???

Comment: have you decorated all your `WCF` methods with `[OperationContract]` annotation?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `PlusAsync` operation because WCF service added in your client as Asynchronously you can also check below image which shows how wcf service get added Asynchronously

[image]

But that might be default behaviour with Mobile application Asynchronously and put callback function in that call to get retun value and display it

Example of calling WCF Asynchronous service

```
    private void MakeAsynchronousCall(int NumberOfStudents)
    {
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        StudentService.StudentServiceClient c =
            new WFCCallExample.StudentService.StudentServiceClient();
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = c.Endpoint.Address;

        StudentService.IStudentService iStudentService =
            new ChannelFactory<StudentService.IStudentService>
            (basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();

        AsyncCallback aSyncCallBack =
            delegate(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                List<StudentService.Student> Students =
                    iStudentService.EndGetStudents(result);

                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
                { DGStudent.ItemsSource = Students; });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
                { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); });
            }
        };

        try
        {
            iStudentService.BeginGetStudents(NumberOfStudents,
                aSyncCallBack, iStudentService);
        } catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
```

Comment: feels like the mobile proxy is async only like in Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

As explained on [How to: Call WCF Service Operations Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), first you create a callback method which processes the result:

```
// Asynchronous callbacks for displaying results.
static void AddCallback(object sender, AddCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add Result: {0}", e.Result);
}
```

Then you subscribe to the Completed event and issue the call:

```
client.AddCompleted += new EventHandler<AddCompletedEventArgs>(AddCallback);
client.AddAsync(value1, value2);
```

As soon as the WCF call returns, your `AddCallback` will be called.

Comment: @Pranay I'm sorry, but that really was a useless edit, so I rolled it back. Inline code tags are for inline code, not for highlighting random terms.